# Open CV Contour area miscalculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am just starting to play with OpenCV and I have found some very strange behaviour from the contourArea function.

See this image.

[image: Original]

It has three non connected areas, the left is a grouping of long strokes and on the top center there is a single dot and finally a big square on the right.

When I run my function, I get this result

[image: Contours detected]

```
Contour[0] Area: 221, Length: 70, Colour: Red 
Contour[1] Area: 13772, Length: 480, Colour: Green 
Contour[2] Area: 150, Length: 2370, Colour: Blue
```

While I havent actually counted the area of the left part, It seems as if it encompasses much more than 150 pixels and would certainly have a higher value than the dot in the top center, I would say that dot should be able to fit in to the left part at least 10 times. The area of the square does work out.

```
Square Area
width = 118
height = 116
118 * 116 = 13,688
```

13,688 is really close to what opencv gave as the area (13,772), the difference is likely measurement error on my behalf.
I manually calculated the area of the dot

```
Dot Area
width = 27
height = 6 
27*6 = 162
```

Not too far off from what opencv said it would be (221)

Reading from the [OpenCV docs page on contourArea](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1) it says that it will give wrong results for contours with self intersections. Not really understanding what self intersections are, I made a test image.

[image: ORIGINAL PIC HERE]

As you can see I have a rectangle on the left and a cross in the middle and another cross rotated 45 deg.
I would expect the cross to have slightly less than double the area of the rectangle due to the overlap in the center.

[image: CONTOURED PIC HERE]

```
Contour[0] Area: 1805, Length: 423, Colour: Red 
Contour[1] Area: 947, Length: 227, Colour: Green 
Contour[2] Area: 1825, Length: 415, Colour: Blue
```

As you can see the area of the two crosses are slightly less than double the area of the rectangle. As expected.

I am not interested in capturing the inside of the square or getting a box drawn around the shape on the left and the dot (though it would be tangentially interesting) it's not specifically what I'm asking about in this question.

So my question: 
Why is the area of my irregular shape severly underestimated?

1. Am I using the wrong function?
2. Am I using the right function incorrectly?
3. Have I found a bug in opencv?
4. Does self intersections have a meaning that wasn't demonstrated in my test?

I copied most of this code from [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d49/tutorial_moments.html)

I have stripped down my code to this self contained example below.

```
def contour_test(name):
    import cv2 as cv
    colours = [{'name': 'Red ',   'bgr': (0, 0, 255)}, 
               {'name': 'Green ', 'bgr': (0, 255, 0)},
               {'name': 'Blue ',  'bgr': (255, 0, 0)}]
    src = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(name))
    src_gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    src_gray = cv.blur(src_gray, (3,3))
    threshold = 100
    canny_output = cv.Canny(src_gray, threshold, threshold * 2)
    contours, _ = cv.findContours(canny_output, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # Get the moments
    mu = [None for i in contours]
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        mu[i] = cv.moments(contours[i])
    # Get the mass centers
    mc = [None for i in contours]
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        mc[i] = (mu[i]['m10'] / (mu[i]['m00'] + 1e-5), mu[i]['m01'] / (mu[i]['m00'] + 1e-5))
    # Draw contours
    drawing = np.zeros((canny_output.shape[0], canny_output.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i, j in enumerate(contours):
        colour = colours[i]['bgr']
        cv.drawContours(drawing, contours, i, colour, 2)
        area = int(cv.contourArea(contours[i]))
        length = int(cv.arcLength(contours[i], True))
        print('Contour[{0}] Area: {1}, Length: {2}, Colour: {3}'.format(i, area, length, colours[i]['name']))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inner part of the contours the `findContours` finds is supposed to be of filled with **white** color.

- Don't use `cv.Canny` before `findContours` (`cv.blur` is also not required).
- Make sure the contours are white and not black.
  You may use `cv.threshold` with `cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV` option for inverting polarity.
  It is recommended to add `cv.THRESH_OTSU` option for automatic threshold.

You may replace `cv.blur` and `cv.Canny` and `cv.findContours(canny_output...` with:

```
_, src_thresh = cv.threshold(src_gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv.THRESH_OTSU)
contours, _ = cv.findContours(src_thresh, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Result (of top image):

[image]

```
Contour[0] Area: 13531, Length: 476, Colour: Red
Contour[1] Area: 184, Length: 71, Colour: Green
Contour[2] Area: 4321, Length: 1202, Colour: Blue
```

---

Here is the complete (updated) code:

```
import numpy as np

def contour_test(name):
    import cv2 as cv
    colours = [{'name': 'Red ',   'bgr': (0, 0, 255)}, 
               {'name': 'Green ', 'bgr': (0, 255, 0)},
               {'name': 'Blue ',  'bgr': (255, 0, 0)}]
    src = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(name))
    src_gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #src_gray = cv.blur(src_gray, (3,3))
    #threshold = 100
    #canny_output = cv.Canny(src_gray, threshold, threshold * 2)
    #contours, _ = cv.findContours(canny_output, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    _, src_thresh = cv.threshold(src_gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv.THRESH_OTSU)
    cv.imshow('src_thresh', src_thresh);cv.waitKey(0);cv.destroyAllWindows()  # Show src_thresh for testing
    contours, _ = cv.findContours(src_thresh, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Get the moments
    mu = [None for i in contours]
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        mu[i] = cv.moments(contours[i])
    # Get the mass centers
    mc = [None for i in contours]
    for i in range(len(contours)):
        mc[i] = (mu[i]['m10'] / (mu[i]['m00'] + 1e-5), mu[i]['m01'] / (mu[i]['m00'] + 1e-5))
    # Draw contours
    drawing = np.zeros((src_thresh.shape[0], src_thresh.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i, j in enumerate(contours):
        colour = colours[i]['bgr']
        cv.drawContours(drawing, contours, i, colour, 2)
        area = int(cv.contourArea(contours[i]))
        length = int(cv.arcLength(contours[i], True))
        print('Contour[{0}] Area: {1}, Length: {2}, Colour: {3}'.format(i, area, length, colours[i]['name']))

    cv.imshow('drawing', drawing);cv.waitKey(0);cv.destroyAllWindows()  # Show drawing for testing

contour_test('img.jpg')
```

I added `cv.imshow` in two places for testing.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that, marked as correct and +1'ed. Do you know why it estimated the solid black dot's area accurately?

Comment: It is marking the [white edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVINn.png) after the Canny filter. `RETR_EXTERNAL` option finds only the outer contours, so result makes sense.